# Removing option from object

Tags: javascript, json

From the database I have something like this coming back.

```
[{
    "Code": "Yes",
    "Name": "Yes",
    "Name_spanish": "S&#237;"
}, {
    "Code": "No",
    "Name": "No",
    "Name_spanish": null
}]
```

and I'm working on switching the name back and forth between english or spanish depending on the key I'm given. However, I can't seem to figure out how to remove the spanish part if it needs to be english and vise versa.

I've tried wrapping a `JSON.parse` around it and then using the `delete objectname.Name` but I have had no luck.

Code looks like this

```
var this.model = viewModel;
var option = viewModel.get('Options');
delete option.Name_spanish;
console.log(option);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Your question lacks two important pieces of information: 1. How does the data in your database look and 2. what's the query you use to retrieve it. Please ad this information so it can be answered.

Comment: Please show us that actual code you tried.  `delete obj.prop`  is the appropriate way to remove a property from a Javascript object if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Philipp, I do not have access to the database so I do not know what it looks like. I am only dealing with the javascript part. and I am retrieving it by grabbing it from the backbone view Model viewModel.get('Options')

Comment: You have an array of objects, so you have to find the index and splice it!

Comment: Similar to what tymeJV just said, after you parse the object you have an array of objects that contain the `name` property. So you have to iterate EACH record in your results and delete the element, e.g. `delete obj[index].name`

Comment: @tymeJV, it is dynamic. The index is going to be different each time I pull the info.

Comment: @zazvorniki -- Yes, so you have to iterate the object, check the properties, and delete that index.

Answer (score 0):

You must iterate your object:

```
var this.model = viewModel;
var option = viewModel.get('Options');

for(var i = 0; i != option.length; ++i)
{
    delete option[i].Name_es_US;
}

console.log(option);
```

**EDIT** Here's a fiddle that demonstrates removing a property, including removing a property dynamically (i.e. property by name stored in a string): http://jsfiddle.net/3vk19fLu/

Comment: +1 (I was just answering this)  The object is an Array of objects, you have to access the index of the object first before deleting the property.

Comment: @zazvorniki I added a fiddle that proves it's gone. either Name_es_US isn't in the property you're looking for, so not sure which is correct. Update your example to more accurately fit what you're trying to do. Better yet, update my jsfiddle example and prove to me that it's not deleting. As you'll see in my fiddle, it's gone!

Comment: The variable names are the same in my code, but I changed them here to make them simpler and forgot to change the one. Even though the fiddle is working, it does not want to work in my code. I just keep getting everything back. Maybe I am just going at this the wrong way.

Comment: Then provide more information. Clearly `delete` is the correct answer. It obviously works. fiddle us an example and prove to me that it's not working.

Comment: I don't have anymore information to provide, if I did I would. All, I can see is that I put it in my code and it's not coming out the way it should. Like I said I think I'm going to the entire situation wrong. Maybe deleting isn't the best option for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: You posted some sample JSON. Can't you give us the REAL json? Can't you give us what gets logged after `var option = viewModel.get('Options');` ? Then we could inject that into the jsfiddle example and test it.

Comment: That is not sample json, that is what I am getting back. Exactly what I am getting back from var option = viewModel.get('Options'); I only changed one of the names because I wanted to make it clearer that it was spanish. It's the name and values for radio buttons that are being thrown into the html using knockout.